# Collapse if function

Tags: jquery

**(jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3o8udgpn/3/)**

I'm trying to collapse (hide) a DIV when someone clicks on a designated div filled with a button. I'm using an if, and (still need to add) will change the class of said "collapse_button_down" to "collapse_button_up" which should render the if as false and execute the 'else' code so that everything returns to it's normal state.

Anyhow, as said above, the code I wrote isn't working as expected. So consider this as a double request with the following questions:

1. Where did I go wrong in this code/ where is the error?
2. Is there an easier way to accomplish what I've described above?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
    <script> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($("collapse").hasClass('collapse_btn_down')){
        $("collapse").click(function(){
                // removes the middle div
            $(".mid_div").toggle( "slow" );
                // "buurtkiezer" class will be changed to stick to the bottom of the 'content_wrap' div
            $('.buurtkiezer').toggleClass("buurtkiezer_solo");
                // content_wrap will get a new height (it's on auto by default, which would otherwise make it 0px)
            $('.content_wrap').css('height', '350px');
                // footer-wrap will get an extra margin so it stays down
            $('.footer_wrap').css('margin-top', '300');
        }};
    else{
        $("collapse").click(function(){
            $(".mid_div").toggle( "slow" );
            $('.buurtkiezer_solo').toggleClass("buurtkiezer");
            $('.content_wrap').css('height', '350px');
            $('.footer_wrap').css('margin-top', '300');             
        }};

}); 
</script>
```

edit: The HTML>

```
    <div class="content_wrap">
    <div class="buurtkiezer"><collapse><div class="collapse_btn_down"></div></collapse> </div>
        <div class="mid_div"> </div>...
```

Comment: Can you fiddle your code?http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: You have a <collapse> tag?

Comment: need to check the condition in the click handler - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fbpcnof8/1/

Comment: Give me a sec, will make the fiddle.

Comment: `<collapse>` is not a legitimate HTML element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking once at load time, so you need to check at click time. Also, as the logic is duplicated, you can compress it using toggle alone (so long as the new class only add new properties):

To increase reusability, I have reworked your example so that it listens for click events on any `collapse_btn_down` classed elements, then applies the changes to the nearest matching elements within the same container. I made the class `buurtkiezer_solo` only add new properties, so you only need to toggle that one class.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'collapse .collapse_btn_down', function () {
        $(this).closest('.buurtkiezer').toggleClass("buurtkiezer_solo");
        $(this).closest('.content_wrap').find('.mid_div').toggle("slow");
        $('.content_wrap').css('height', '350px');
        $('.footer_wrap').css('margin-top', '300');
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3o8udgpn/6/

It would be more helpful if you explain the overall aim, and more details of the page, but hopefully this will help you with the immediate problems.

If you prefer a standard click handler it would be:

```
$('.collapse_btn_down').click(function() {
```

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/3o8udgpn/) Here's the fiddle.
I'm working on a page with an interactive Gmaps background, so to make it easier for users to use said background, I want to be able to hide/collapse all 'mid_div' content.

I'm trying to achieve this by .toggle-ing the mid div, but this would place the remaining content ('buurtkiezer') in the middle of the page, hence the .toggleClass("buurtkiezer_solo"). When 'collapse_btn_down" is clicked, it should change its class to "collapse_btn_up" so everything returns to its normale state when clicked again.

Comment: My bad, accidentally pressed enter whilst writing my reply. Edited my reply with the requested info.

Comment: @Kay Angevare: Have a play with the new answer and see what is missing. It is usually a bad idea to toggle more than one class name on elements, as one will usually do, but I am still not sure of your intentions :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answering and bearing my inaccurate description of the problem, I'm new to Jquery (and haven't had enough coffee yet) so I'm kinda confused myself. I'll rewrite the code with your answer alongside. If anything, your answer has atleast helped me understand the logic behind the process, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Basic rule to follow: Toggle single classes if possible (and have that class override newly required styles only).

Comment: Thanks again! I eventually ended up using the following: (http://jsfiddle.net/va5o0adv/) I did not realise that .toggleClass removes a class and returns the changed value (in this case the height) to its original state when used for the second time. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It simply removes that style and therefore the styled height. Second rule, try to use styles and not set css values directly (like the footer margin-top)

Answer (score 1):

Where you have went wrong—the order of the logic. You should be binding the click event first, and then using the if-else condition to evaluate whether the clicked element has the class or not: and not the other way round.

The danger you have is that you are binding the click event based on the class `.collapse` has at **runtime**, which makes it static. It is more effective to bind the click event at runtime regardless of the situation, and evaluate the class later.

You should also note that the things you are doing in your question's if/else statement is **exactly identical**, so you might want to re-evaluate your situation, context or code.

`<collapse>` is not a legitimate HTML element. Are you trying to create a toggle button instead?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('collapse').click(function() {
        // Common function
        $(".mid_div").toggle( "slow" );
        $('.content_wrap').css('height', '350px');
        $('.footer_wrap').css('margin-top', '300');    

        // If/else
        if($(this).hasClass('collapse_btn_down')) {
            // If has class, do this
            $('.buurtkiezer').toggleClass("buurtkiezer_solo");
        } else {
            // If does not have class, do this
            $('.buurtkiezer_solo').toggleClass("buurtkiezer");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Three-quarters of the conditions are identical on each branch of the `if`. May as well move them outside.

Comment: @Jamiec That's taken from OP's code... not sure what he/she really wants to achieve, but the inherent logic is incorrect and that is what that should be corrected. With regards to what he/she wants to achieve in the if/else conditional is up to his/her purview.

Comment: They're not "exactly identical" as you've now updated. One out of 4 of the lines differs (`$('.buurtkiezer').toggleClass("buurtkiezer_solo");` vs `$('.buurtkiezer_solo').toggleClass("buurtkiezer");`)

Comment: Updated answer based on new information OP has provided.

Comment: Yes, a toggle button is basically what I'm trying to achieve.

Should I be using an if-statement at all?